# Image loading taking more time in swift

Tags: swift, imageview, alamofire

I am working on an application, where I am loading some images from the server and showing it on table view using Alamofire. But the problem is it is taking so much time to load the image. I want to show the image, like a blurry image until the time image is not loading. Please, someone, help me.

```
 cell.profileImageView?.pin_setImage(from: URL(string: modelArray[indexPath.row]))
```

Comment: tried using `AlamofireImage` library and using the method `af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: phImage)` where placeholder image is the one blurring thing you're talking about.

Comment: I would suggest using Kingfisher, it has a loader until image loaded, for me is the best solution

Comment: Can we make it like facebook? An animation is there on the image until the image loaded.

Comment: yes of course, but I think this is a very clean and useful way to load images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is the solution using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) pod. You can set an activity Indicator while image is loaded.

```
 let imageUrl =  modelArray[indexPath.row]
    //set activity indicator until image is loaded
    cell.profileImageView?.kf.indicatorType = .activity
    if let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL:  url)
        cell.profileImageView?.kf.setImage(with: resource)
    }
```